# Como usar o su renomeado

Tags: linux

Alguém sabe como faço pra usar o root no prompt/terminal, porem com o su renomeado pra suu?

eu tentei digitar suu - no terminal não deu.

Comment: Não ficou clara sua dúvida, pra que este suu ?

Answer (score 1):

Se foi o que eu entendi, com seu usuário logado digita "su", no seu caso que renomeou "suu" coloca a sua senha de root, assim vc fica com as permissão de root. Se bem que o correto é eles usarem o comando 'sudo' para realizar operações com privilégio de root.

Caso precisar no console use "sudo konqueror"

que abrirá o gerenciador de arquivos com privilégios de root. aí pode renomear..etc..etc.